# How to insert horizontal line in iTunes app description?

Tags: iphone, itunes, app-store-connect

I'd like to have something like the html tag:

< h r >

---

Can someone tell me how to do this? I've seen other apps do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ASCII ART

---

The underscore character (just to the right of the '0' on US Keyboards) works well.

Comment: I'll up your answer if you know how many characters to form a complete horizontal line.